# Programación orientada a objetos- Funciones __repr__()/ error <__main__.Banco object at 0x000001B807B044C0>

Tags: python, python-3.x, poo, objeto, excepciones

Dada una **Clase Banco** y una **Clase cuenta** ya definidas. Necesito crear una función que dada información sobre un banco, cree una representación formal de ella.

Las clases son las siguientes:

```
class ExcepcionDeCuenta(Exception):
    pass
class ExcepcionDeBanco(Exception):
    pass
class Cuenta(object):
 def __init__(self,num_cuenta,titulares,saldo):
     self.titulares = {}
     for dni, nombre in titulares:
         self.add_titular(dni,nombre)
         self.num_cuenta = num_cuenta
         self.saldo = saldo
 def add_titular(self,dni,nombre):
    if dni in self.titulares:
            raise ExcepcionDeCuenta("Titular repetido:{}".format(dni))
    else:
        self.titulares[dni] = nombre
 def __eq__(self, other):
     return self.num_cuenta == other.num_cuenta
 def __hash__(self):
     return hash(self.num_cuenta)
 
class Banco(object):
 def __init__(self,nombre):
     self.nombre = nombre
     self.cuentas = set()
 def add_cuenta(self,cuenta):
    if cuenta in self.cuentas:
         raise ExcepcionDeBanco("Cuenta repetida:{}".format(cuenta.num_cuenta))
    else:
        self.cuentas.add(cuenta)
```

Tengo que escribir los métodos de las clases que devuelven una representación textual, de modo que el código siguiente produzca la salida mostrada:

```
>> cuenta1 = Cuenta(1234,[("111A","Pepe Pinillo"),("222B","Aquiles Bailo")],299.99)
>> cuenta2 = Cuenta(5678, [("333C","Aquiles Salto"),("444D","Ana Liza")], 199.75)
>> banco = Banco("Banco Sandandtar")
>> banco.add_cuenta(cuenta1)
>> banco.add_cuenta(cuenta2)
>> print(banco)
Banco Sandandtar
1234 : (111A, Pepe Pinillo), (222B, Aquiles Bailo) : 299.99
5678 : (333C, Aquiles Salto), (444F, Ana Liza) : 199.75
```

Tengo esta función :

```
 def __repr__(self):
 representacion="self.nombre \n"
 for cuenta in self. cuentas:
     representacion=representacion + "cuenta.num_cuenta:"
     for dni,nombre in cuenta.titulares:
            if len (cuenta.titulares)>1:
               representacion+= "(dni,nombre),"
               del cuenta.titulares[dni]
            else:
                 representacion+= "(dni,nombre):"            
     representacion+= "cuenta.saldo"   
 return representacion
```

Pero me da este error `<__main__.Banco object at 0x000001B807B044C0>` y no se como solucionarlo

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

La solución es definir el método `__repr__` apropiado a cada clase.

#### Clase Cuenta

```
def __repr__(self):
    lista = [f"({k}, {v})"  for k, v in self.titulares.items()]
    return f"{self.num_cuenta} : {', '.join(lista)} : {self.saldo}"
```

Primero creamos una lista de `(id, nombre)` usando comprensión de listas. La expresión `self.titulares.items()` devuelve la información del diccionario como un par `k, v` (llave, valor).

Luego aplicamos `join` para colapsar la lista de titulares en un solo string, el que insertamos entre el número de cuenta y su saldo.

#### Clase Banco

```
def __repr__(self):
    lista = [self.nombre, *[str(cuenta) for cuenta in self.cuentas]]
    return '\n'.join(lista)
```

Creamos una lista con el nombre del banco, seguido de las cuentas. A esta lista le aplicamos un `join` para formar las líneas de texto.

Es la clase `Cuenta` la que se encarga de formatear la cuenta para su representación. Aquí sólo aplicamos `str` para invocar su método `__repr__`.

El asterisco delante de la comprensión de lista la convierta en una colección de elementos individuales.

#### Demo

```
Banco Sandandtar
1234 : (111A, Pepe Pinillo), (222B, Aquiles Bailo) : 299.99
5678 : (333C, Aquiles Salto), (444D, Ana Liza) : 199.75

Process finished with exit code 0
```